# I have a list of links for a drop down menu and i am adding a new link to click but i dont want to go through every file to add to the copy paste

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to have a centralized menu like CSS files where you change it at the source and all the files change but for lists. I'm trying to add a new link to the menu without having to go to each file on the website to add to the copy and pasted list that we have.

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <ul class="links">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></li>
      <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="sponsorForm.html">Sponsor Application</a></li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="mediaMain.html">Media</a></li>
      <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="Season2019.html">2019 Season</a></li>
        <li><a href="Season2018.html">2018 Season</a></li>
        <li><a href="Season2017.html">2017 Season</a></li>
        <li><a href="mediaMain.html">View More Seasons</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

being able to add a html to the list and it changes for every part you go to.

Comment: I had the same problem before, but the solution is to **include HTML** I think [*this*](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) would be the solution of your problem. (by [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/))

Comment: im not having an error or anything. What i want to do is, the code for the html menu is in one spot in the code, like CSS, and when i change the menu in that one spot it changes the menu for every other part of the website. its hard for me to explain but what i can point to for an example would be clicking on a link to go to a different part of your website. then the menu thats on every part of the website has the same stuff.

Comment: You need to look into PHP and serving the menu separately.